# Log file bloat due to nouveau

Tags: log-files, kernel, syslog

Both my kern.log and syslog files have grown to >50Gb and contain a few hundred million lines of:

```
Feb 23 23:32:43 Yawning-Angel kernel: [396111.179453] nouveau E[   PFIFO][0000:05:00.0] PBDMA0: ch 2 [Xorg[1074]] subc 0 mthd 0x001c data 0x00001004
Feb 23 23:32:43 Yawning-Angel kernel: [396111.179469] nouveau E[   PFIFO][0000:05:00.0] PBDMA0: ACQUIRE
Feb 23 23:32:43 Yawning-Angel kernel: [396111.179472] nouveau E[   PFIFO][0000:05:00.0] PBDMA0: ch 1 [DRM] subc 0 mthd 0x001c data 0x00001004
Feb 23 23:32:43 Yawning-Angel kernel: [396111.179489] nouveau E[   PFIFO][0000:05:00.0] PBDMA0: ACQUIRE
Feb 23 23:32:43 Yawning-Angel kernel: [396111.179490] nouveau E[   PFIFO][0000:05:00.0] PBDMA0: ch 2 [Xorg[1074]] subc 0 mthd 0x001c data 0x00001004
Feb 23 23:32:43 Yawning-Angel kernel: [396111.179507] nouveau E[   PFIFO][0000:05:00.0] PBDMA0: ACQUIRE
Feb 23 23:32:43 Yawning-Angel kernel: [396111.179509] nouveau E[   PFIFO][0000:05:00.0] PBDMA0: ch 1 [DRM] subc 0 mthd 0x001c data 0x00001004
Feb 23 23:32:43 Yawning-Angel kernel: [396111.179525] nouveau E[   PFIFO][0000:05:00.0] PBDMA0: ACQUIRE
Feb 23 23:32:43 Yawning-Angel kernel: [396111.179527] nouveau E[   PFIFO][0000:05:00.0] PBDMA0: ch 2 [Xorg[1074]] subc 0 mthd 0x001c data 0x00001004
Feb 23 23:32:43 Yawning-Angel kernel: [396111.179543] nouveau E[   PFIFO][0000:05:00.0] PBDMA0: ACQUIRE
Feb 23 23:32:43 Yawning-Angel kernel: [396111.179545] nouveau E[   PFIFO][0000:05:00.0] PBDMA0: ch 1 [DRM] subc 0 mthd 0x001c data 0x00001004
Feb 23 23:32:43 Yawning-Angel kernel: [396111.179562] nouveau E[   PFIFO][0000:05:00.0] PBDMA0: ACQUIRE
Feb 23 23:32:43 Yawning-Angel kernel: [396111.179564] nouveau E[   PFIFO][0000:05:00.0] PBDMA0: ch 2 [Xorg[1074]] subc 0 mthd 0x001c data 0x00001004
Feb 23 23:32:43 Yawning-Angel kernel: [396111.179581] nouveau E[   PFIFO][0000:05:00.0] PBDMA0: ACQUIRE
Feb 23 23:32:43 Yawning-Angel kernel: [396111.179584] nouveau E[   PFIFO][0000:05:00.0] PBDMA0: ch 1 [DRM] subc 0 mthd 0x001c data 0x00001004
Feb 23 23:32:43 Yawning-Angel kernel: [396111.179600] nouveau E[   PFIFO][0000:05:00.0] PBDMA0: ACQUIRE
Feb 23 23:32:43 Yawning-Angel kernel: [396111.179602] nouveau E[   PFIFO][0000:05:00.0] PBDMA0: ch 2 [Xorg[1074]] subc 0 mthd 0x001c data 0x00001004
Feb 23 23:32:43 Yawning-Angel kernel: [396111.179619] nouveau E[   PFIFO][0000:05:00.0] PBDMA0: ACQUIRE
```

Its odd that this is happening when the computer should be idle (11PM at night on a work computer in a locked room). It also seems recent since the last few sets of log-files are in the Kb range.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you considered that you may have a hardware problem? It could also be a bug in the driver, or in the software you are running.

Comment: Seems [like a bug in nvidia drivers](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2265645), also seems like offtopic...